# Numberpicker throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when scrolling through the values

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception, numberpicker

hey I have a simple NumberPicker with 15 values (100,200,300,400,...,1500).
And when I scroll through the numbers, the numberpicker throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I come to the number 1400 (position 13). See log below.

But I really have no idea. It seems that is a bug of the numberpicker class.

**Here's my code:**

```
 tv_radius.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CostLogActivity2.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.radius_picker);
                dialog.setTitle("Radius");

                NumberPicker np_radius = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.np_radius);

                 np_radius.setMaxValue(100); // max value 100
                 np_radius.setMinValue(1);   // min value 1
                 np_radius.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

                String[] displayedValues = new String[15];
                int x=0;
                 for(int i=0; i<displayedValues.length; i++){
                     x = x+100;
                     displayedValues[i] = Integer.toString(x);

                 }

                 np_radius.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues);

                np_radius.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }               

        });
```

**ErrorLog:**

```
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=15
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.ensureCachedScrollSelectorValue(NumberPicker.java:1774)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.incrementSelectorIndices(NumberPicker.java:1739)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.scrollBy(NumberPicker.java:1008)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.computeScroll(NumberPicker.java:964)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2729)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10475)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10475)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10475)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10475)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11041)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2151)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10477)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:873)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1638)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2452)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4464)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:589)
04-07 13:55:33.383: E/AndroidRuntime(20233):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a bug. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

The length of the displayed values array must be equal to the range of selectable numbers which is equal to `getMaxValue() - getMinValue() + 1`.

Your `maxValue` is 100, and `minValue` is 1. So, just use this instead:

```
numberPicker.setMaxValue(14);
numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
```

You can also take a look [here](https://shanetully.com/2011/12/android-3-x-and-4-x-numberpicker-example/)

Answer (score 1):

Android documentation for your issue is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

The problem lies in this piece of code `np_radius.setMaxValue(100)`. You should replace this line with `np_radius.setMaxValue(14)`.

Comment: no I tried this at beginning. Thats not the problem. it doesnt work either

Comment: Oops. I accidentally put `setMaxValue(20)` instead of `setMaxValue(15)`. Why don't you give it another try? Either way the `np_radius.setMaxValue(100)` will cause you issues.